# Updating Winforms Label with Timer and Thread, stock app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Gist of it has probably been asked before, but I'm completely lost so I'm looking for some personal guidance. Been trying to make a stock tracker app for funsies using WinForms and the Yahoo API. Trying to get it so you can input a tracker symbol and it will make a new Label that will keep updating itself every so often. However, it keeps giving me error messages about "Cross-thread operation not valid". I've tried to do some googling, but yeah, completely lost. Here is most of the code, hope you guys can make some sense of it.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using YahooFinanceApi;

namespace stockpoging4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Prompt prompt = new Prompt("Enter the ticker symbol", "Add ticker"))
            {
                string result = prompt.Result;
                result = result.ToUpper();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    do_Things(result);
                }
            }
        }
        public async Task<string> getStockPrices(string symbol)
        {
            try
            {
                var securities = await Yahoo.Symbols(symbol).Fields(Field.RegularMarketPrice).QueryAsync();
                var aapl = securities[symbol];
                var price = aapl[Field.RegularMarketPrice];
                return symbol + " $" + price;

            }
            catch
            {
                return "404";
            }
        }


        public async void do_Things(string result)
        {
            string price;
            Label label = null;

            if (label == null)
            {
                price = await getStockPrices(result);
                label = new Label() { Name = result, Text = result + " $" + price };
                flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread testThread = new Thread(async delegate ()
                {
                    uiLockingTask();
                    price = await getStockPrices(result);
                    label.Text = result + " $" + price;
                    label.Update();
                });
            }
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            timer.Start();
            timer.Elapsed += do_Things(results);
        }

        private void uiLockingTask() {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any relation in `label == null` and executing something on a thread which uses the `label`... Creating a simple "timer/loop" using async/await on the UI thread (without blocking) is easy. I'll try to make an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me point out several things in your implementation.

1. You subscribe to timer.Elapsed after timer.Start that might be invalid in case of a short-timer interval
2. The event handler is called in background that's why you continuously get "Cross-thread operation not valid". UI components should be dispatched correctly from background threads, for example, by calling flowLayoutPanel2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label))); and label.BeginInvoke(new Action(label.Update)). This change already would fix your exception.
3. Despite the fact that I would implement this functionality in a different way, here I post slightly changed code that just does exactly what you need with some tweaks.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
        Task _runningTask;
        CancellationTokenSource _cancellationToken;
    
        public Form1()
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Prompt prompt = new Prompt("Enter the ticker symbol", "Add ticker"))
            {
                string result = prompt.Result;
                result = result.ToUpper();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    do_Things(result);
                    _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    _runningTask = StartTimer(() => do_Things(result), _cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    
        private void onCancelClick()
        {
            _cancellationToken.Cancel();
        }
    
    
        public async Task<string> getStockPrices(string symbol)
        {
            try
            {
                var securities = await Yahoo.Symbols(symbol).Fields(Field.RegularMarketPrice).QueryAsync();
                var aapl = securities[symbol];
                var price = aapl[Field.RegularMarketPrice];
                return symbol + " $" + price;
    
            }
            catch
            {
                return "404";
            }
        }
    
        private async Task StartTimer(Action action, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                    action();
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        }
    
    
        public async void do_Things(string result)
        {
            var price = await getStockPrices(result);
            var label = new Label() { Name = result, Text = result + " $" + price };
            flowLayoutPanel2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I just copied the code and it seems to be doing the trick, except that it keeps printing new labels instead of updating the existing one. I'm gonna take a better look at the code to try and understand/add to it it, but thanks a bunch for this regardless!

Comment: No problem. I would be happy if you mark my answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way is using async these days.

Here is a class which triggers an `Action` every interval:

```
public class UITimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // use a private function which returns a task
    private async Task Innerloop(TimeSpan interval, Action<UITimer> action)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(interval, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                action(this);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    }

    // the constructor calls the private StartTimer, (the first part will run synchroniously, until the away delay) 
    public UITimer(TimeSpan interval, Action<UITimer> action) =>
        _ = Innerloop(interval, action);

    // make sure the while loop will stop.
    public void Dispose() =>
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
}
```

If you work with dotnet 3.0 or higher, you can use the IAsyncDisposable. With this you're able to await the `DisposeAsync` method, so you can await the `_timerTask` to be finished.

And I created a new form with this as code behind:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly UITimer _uiTimer;
    private int _counter;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // setup the time and pass the callback action
        _uiTimer = new UITimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Update);
    }

    // the orgin timer is passed as parameter.
    private void Update(UITimer timer)
    {
        // do your thing on the UI thread.
        _counter++;
        label1.Text= _counter.ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // make sure the time (whileloop) is stopped.
        _uiTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The advantage is, that the callback runs on the UI thread but doesn't block it. The `await Task.Delay(..)` is using a Timer in the background, but posts the rest of the method/statemachine on the UI thread *(because the UI thread has a SynchronizaionContext)*

Easy but does the trick ;-)